# Icon for "manual ping"

Tags: icon, symbolism

I have an app that connects to a server (a computer) over bluetooth. Once the connection is made, there are chances that the connection drops (because the user can physically switch of bluetooth) so I have a mechanism to "ping" and check if the server is up and running.I want users to manually be able to ping a server.

**Because "ping" is somewhat a technical term, how do I represent it graphically ?**

One approach that I found with quick googling was to show a doorbell with a hand, something like this :

[image: Ping Idea]

(image via iconfinder.com)

This is an Android app and the icon will appear as an action button.

Comment: Hello and welcome t GD.SE you shoudl probably be asking this question on [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @joojaa UX.SE migrates posts like this to here. It's not on topic there

Comment: @MarkMussler sucks but its not really on topic here either, so they should be denied the migration. I dont oppose keeping the question open but its still clearly a violation of rules and asking for free work. Shivek Khurana, see [this post](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/183/update-faq-to-disallow-general-brainstorming-and-idea-gathering)

Comment: Howabout a connection symbol https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=connection

Comment: Waves with a question mark rather than an antenna in the middle: ((?))

Comment: The approach you came up with is a icon from iconfinder.com

Comment: @timhuman : Yes. It's a a direct link to an image I found on icon finder.

Comment: @joojaa : I saw the icons tagged "connection" and landed on to a related tag : "antenna". Although icons under "connection" were good enough, "antenna" makes more sense :) https://thenounproject.com/term/antenna/

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution might be to not have a ping icon at all.

> I have an app that connects to a server (a computer) over bluetooth. Once the connection is made, there are chances that the connection drops

I’ve spoken to a developer friend and Bluetooth disconnect/connect are events your app can register for. That seems like a far more sane way to go. That way you won’t need a ping icon, you’ll just have to handle the disconnection state. Far nicer for the user.

> (because the user can physically switch off Bluetooth) so I have a mechanism to "ping" and check if the server is up and running. I want users to manually be able to ping a server.

You can actually just check if the device supports Bluetooth and then check to see if it’s enabled, with `isEnabled()`. Google’s documents cover what’s needed.

#### Android Bluetooth documentation

> Next, you need to ensure that Bluetooth is enabled. Call isEnabled() to check whether Bluetooth is currently enable. If this method returns false, then Bluetooth is disabled.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the input @Marc. Handling a dropped connection gracefully (progmatically) will be a great plus. This is going to my todo list straight away.

Comment: This is a good answer, but very much the UX solution. So, as such, I'd vote that the question be migrated back to UX.

Answer (score 0):

I like your approach but I think it's halfway there.

The hand gesture is great but it doesn't represent the the action result will be a ping. Here's a few suggestions (roughly done):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok but could you please not make icons that span the page this much in the future :)

Comment: Thank you @Naty for giving a kick-start and  putting in the hard work. All illustrations are great but I like the second one the most. I'll design this further :)

Comment: Using the Bluetooth rune instead of what people now associate with wi-fi might be more specific as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an icon similar to the phone field strength (I mean, the 3-5 vertical bars that indicates the quality of a phone call) as seen in many video games. You could change the icon depending on the ping.

Answer (score 0):

There's no right answer to this. What icon you should use here is likely heavily dependent on the rest of the icons in your app.

All that said, I don't think a hand with a finger makes any sense as an icon here, as it's communicating what to do, rather than what it is.

I'd suggest using a front-desk bell:

https://thenounproject.com/term/bell/79519/